# Integrating complex functions over the unit circle

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_c \bar z dz$$ where the contour is the unit circle.

I know the limits of $\theta$ is $0 \to 2\pi$
How do I get to the answer of $2\pi i$?

Comment: On the unit circle $\bar z= \frac{1}{z}$

Comment: @orangeskid Do I not need to put it into polar form so $ \bar z=Re^{i\theta}$

Comment: You could certainly just use the definition and set $z= e^{it}$ ( $R=1$ on the circle) .

Comment: @orangeskid So have $\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}dz$

Comment: now $dz= i e^{i \theta} d \theta$, plug in and integrate a constant function..

Comment: @orangeskid thank you